# How to get SVN changelog in Jenkins Workflow Plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I would like to be able to to do some special stuff in my workflow only when there were changes in specific directory in SVN.

For that purpose I would like to be able access the changelog of the current build.

I know they are storred in:

```
changelog<number>.xml
```

How can I read them in groovy script?

I'm using:

```
Jenkins 1.627, Workflow 1.10, Svn plugin 2.5.2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are low-level ways of getting at this information currently, if you are not using the Groovy sandbox, I filed [JENKINS-30412](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30412) for a supported and documented feature that could be used safely from any script.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. Here it is:

```
node ('master') {
    dir ("${env.JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${env.JOB_NAME}/builds/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}") {
        int changelogNumber = 0;
        while(true){
            String changelogFile = "changelog${changelogNumber}.xml";
            if (fileExists(changelogFile)) {
                String changelogFileContents = readFile(changelogFile)
                // check changes in special dir
            } else {
                break;
            }
            changelogNumber++;
        }
    }
}
```

Still I'm not sure what can cause the changelogs be empty:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins     6 Sep  8 16:04 changelog0.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins     6 Sep  8 16:04 changelog1.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins     6 Sep  8 16:04 changelog2.xml
```

Even though I can see in the logs some SCM changes:

```
Running: General SCM
Updating svn://<my_repository> at revision '2015-09-08T16:04:40.627 +0200'
U         <path>/<file>.txt
...
```

Comment: `"${env.JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${env.JOB_NAME}/builds/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"` will only work in certain cases. Better to use `currentBuild.rawBuild.rootDir.absolutePath`. Even better is to use `currentBuild.rawBuild.changeSets`, which is a parsed `List<ChangeLogSet>`.

Comment: but this leads to this error in recent versions:
`org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper getRawBuild`